# Exercise with toString() method

Tags: java, tostring

i am pretty much new in Java and i have one perhaps easy question.

I have this code :

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean isMan;

    Person(String nameParam,int ageParam,boolean isManParam) {
        this.name = nameParam;
        this.age = ageParam;
        this.isMan = isManParam;
    }
}
```

In another demoClass i have initialized object of class Person:

```
public class toStringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Person human = new Person("Jack",28,true);
    }
}
```

I have a task to write a method showPersonInfo() using toString() method so to 
display all the three fields of the initialized object ..Any help?

Comment: Have you at least tried something?

Comment: You can override `toString()` method of `Person` Class to display these fields.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: You are expected to do serious research prior posting questions. If you did that, you are doing a great job of hiding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toString` method always exists for each Java class. But if you do not override it to specify what to return it will by default return the "*class name, then ‘at’ sign, and at the end hashCode*", something like `Person@19821f`. More info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/).

So you should override the `toString` method in `Person` like this (do change the resulting `String` to taste):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
      String s = name +", age "+age+", isMan: "+isMan;
      return s;
}
```

Then to display this, create the `showPersonInfo` method:

```
public void showPersonInfo(){

   System.out.println(this.toString()); // OR
   // System.out.println(this); // Java prints the toString method by default

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is working and i think this is quite a good knowledge for me, i will explore it :)

Comment: My pleasure! If you are satisfied with the answer, you should mark it as the accepted answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person {

String name;
int age;
boolean isMan;


Person(String nameParam,int ageParam,boolean isManParam){
    this.name = nameParam;
    this.age = ageParam;
    this.isMan = isManParam;
     }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name:" + this.name + ", age:" + this.age + ", isMan:" + this.isMan ;
}

public void showPersonInfo {
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean isMan;

    Person(String nameParam,int ageParam,boolean isManParam) {
        this.name = nameParam;
        this.age = ageParam;
        this.isMan = isManParam;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.name +
               "\nAge: " + this.age +
               "\nIs a Man?: " + this.isMan;
    }

    public String showPersonInfo() {
        return this.toString();
    }
}
```

In your main method:

```
public class toStringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person human = new Person("Jack",28,true);

        System.out.println(human.showPersonInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person
{

       String name;
       int age;
       boolean isMan;
      Person( String name,int age,boolean isMan)   
       {
         this.name=name;
         this.age=age;
          this.isMan=isMan;
       }
       @Override
       public String toString()
        {
          return "name: "+name+"\nage: "+age+"\nisMan: "+isMan;
         }
      
    }
public class ToString
 {
    
          public static void main(String args[])
           {
             Person human=new Person("jack",28,true);
             System.out.println(human);
             //System.out.println(human.toString);
           }
}
```

Comment: How is this an improvement over the previous answers?